# Understanding how to read LVM attributes and filesystem permissions

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, lvm

I'm doing some reverse engineering on Dell OS10 (Debian Stretch under the hood) for giggles because I think it's really cool how it works and I was looking at one of the files responsible for creating bridges. I wanted to play with it to test how I thought the command flow worked coming from above but  even as root, it said it was read-only:

```
"/alt/opt/dell/os10/lib/python/dn_base_br_tool.py" [readonly] 263 lines, 6785 characters
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So I went and checked the permissions for the mount:

```
root@OS10:/alt/opt/dell/os10/bin# df -P /alt/opt/dell/os10/lib/python/dn_base_br_tool.py | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
/dev/mapper/OS10-SYSROOT
root@OS10:/alt/opt/dell/os10/bin#
root@OS10:/alt/opt/dell/os10/bin# lvs
  LV      VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  LICENSE OS10 -wi-ao---- 32.00m
  SYSROOT OS10 -wi-ao---- 13.50g
```

I went and looked up what `-wi-ao` means and based on [this explanation](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3543871). Based on that I see the following

- attribute 2 = writeable
- attribute 3 = inherited
- attribute 5 = active volume
- attribute 6 = open volume

I thought maybe there could be an ACL but it doesn't seem like that's it either:

```
root@OS10:/alt/opt/dell/os10/bin# ls -la /alt/opt/dell/os10/lib/python/dn_base_br_tool.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6785 Jun 16  2020 /alt/opt/dell/os10/lib/python/dn_base_br_tool.py
```

The question is - why is that file read only?

Comment: Ah - that would to be it. `/dev/mapper/OS10-SYSROOT /alt ext4 ro,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0`. I remounted with `sudo mount -o remount,rw /alt` and it popped right up. Thanks! If you throw that in an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: Comment converted to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `/proc/mounts` to see the actual mount options for the filesystem.

`lvs` only tells about the LVM layer: even when LV has been activated in writeable mode, it is still possible to mount the filesystem in read-only mode if so desired.

The file might also be marked "immutable" within the filesystem - see `lsattr /alt/opt/dell/os10/lib/python/dn_base_br_tool.py`.